# Unable to change Lifetime(time_to_live ) firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to change `time_to_live(ttl)` but every request value is not changed. It is still the  default value, 2419200.
My request:

```
{
   "to" : "ceJDlGJ2TJOPd0keLowpF....",  
    "notification":{
       "title":"my title",
       "body":"my body"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"3600s"
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5"
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"3600"
       }
     }
   }
```